# Find rows with same some_attribute but two different values for user_id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel

These are my classes & relations

```
class User
  has_many :conversation_participants
  has_many :conversations, :through => :conversation_participants
end

class ConversationParticipant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation
  has_many :messages
  has_many :conversation_participants
  has_many :users, :through => :conversation_participants
end
```

So when I want to create a conversation between user_ids 12 and 15, I first want to check if a conversation between these two already exists. So what I need to find is this:

> ConversationParticipants where user_id IN (12, 15) AND "both conversationparticipant rows have the same conversation id"

I lack the proper words to explain this query but I think everyone will get what I mean. "Does a conversation between these two users exist already?". I know neither how to do it in SQL nor Rails so any answer is appreciated.

**EDIT**
The id of the conversation would not be known. I need to find **if** a conversation between those two user_ids exist.

Thanks 
-- Emil

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :conversation_participants
  has_many :joined_conversations, :through => :conversation_participants, :source => :conversation
end

class ConversationParticipant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :conversation_participants
  has_many :speakers, :through => :conversation_participants, :source => :user
end
```

Comment: belongs_to :user would imply that there's a user_id column in the conversations table, which there is not. I'll add the schema sometime tonight when I'm at my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 @result = ConversationParticipants.where("user_id in ? AND conversation_id=?",[1,2,3,4],2)
```